# How to render or print node preprocess within the region template

Tags: drupal, theming

I'm doing an entity reference to fetch a node from under a specific content. I'm looking to how I can render the entity reference function I've just created to my `region.html.twig` template. Below is a snippet of the code I'm currently working on

```
// Page region level pre-processing
function iom_preprocess_region(&$variables) {


    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
        $variables['content_type'] = $node->bundle();
    }


    $elements = $variables['elements'];

    if (array_key_exists('#entity', $elements)) {
        $region = $elements['#region'];
        $entity = $elements['#entity'];
        $bundle = _overrideBundle($entity->bundle());

        preprocess($region, 'region', $entity, $variables);
        preprocess($region."_{$bundle}", 'region', $entity, $variables);
    }
}
```

---

```
function _preprocess_country_regional_offices_node($entity, &$variables) {

    $entityStorage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
    $regionalOffices = \Drupal::service('entity.query')
        ->get('node')
        ->condition('status', 1, '=')
        ->condition('type', 'regional_office')
        ->condition('field_primary_offices', '1')
        ->sort('created', 'DESC')
        ->execute();

    $regionalOfficeEntities = $entityStorage->loadMultiple($regionalOffices);
    $variables['regional_office'] = $regionalOfficeEntities;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this using an exposed block, but if you need to do it in code for a specific reason then..

```
$output = render(
  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('node')
  ->view($node, 'teaser')
);
```